# Evaluate a user inputted equation with two variables within a function

Tags: python, function

```
function=print(input('Enter a function in terms of x and y: '))

def f(x,y):
    evaluated=eval(function)
    return evaluated

print(f(1,2))
```

I chose x=1 and y = 2 at random, but I need to have the function working for different x and y values throughout my program.

Comment: The variable function is being set to None (i.e. the result of print).

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by 'the function being set to None'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the print from your input line and your code becomes.

```
def f(x,y):
    evaluated = eval(function)
    return evaluated

function = input('Enter a function in terms of x and y: ')
print(f(1,2))
```

Using eval in this way is unsafe for production code.

It can be made safer by following [Using eval() safely in python](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html)

**Issue with Posted Code**

```
function=print(input('Enter a function in terms of x and y: '))
```

In this line whatever the user inputs is printed to the screen by the print routine.

The print routine returns None which is assigned to function.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
function = input('Enter a function in terms of x and y: ')

def f(x, y):
    evaluated = eval(function)
    return evaluated

x = int(input('x: '))
y = int(input('y: '))

print(f(x, y))
```

Comment: Hi, I would like for a user to input a function and for the answer of the function (for any x an y value I choose) to be outputted. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Gotcha, I edited the answer. Pretty much what the other SO members are pointing you towards too. Make sure to follow the `eval` advice by DarryIG.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for.

```
def f(x,y):
  evaluated = eval(function)
  return evaluated

function = input("Enter a function in terms of x and y:")
x = int(input("Enter a number"))
y = int(input("Enter a number"))
print(f(x,y))
```

Although the use of eval() this way is not recommended as suggested by @DarrylG

Also in your code,

```
function=print(input('Enter a function in terms of x and y: '))
```

You seem to have assigned a print statement to a variable, which returns a none. The variable thus gets assigned to NoneType.